# Limit Apache 2.4 mod_rewrite allowed flags

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to limit the allowed RewriteRule flags on my Apache 2.4 server.
Especially, I don't want that users can use the "H" flag in order to define another handler for this request.

Example:

```
RewriteRule \.php$ - [H=proxy:unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1:4321/]
```

This should not be allowed to users in order to force them to use their own FPM instance.
Is there any way I can restrict the usable flags in mod_rewrite without disabling it completely?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you can disable some flags. Either it's all or nothing. I haven't found anything with google. Someone using Apache (I don't :D) can possibly answer your question better.

Comment: Thank you, then I must head over to another way to enforce usage of the correct FPM instance.